# How to use chromedriver in selenium in all platforms like mac,linux and windows?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Actually I'm doing a project on creating a **library package** to add in PIP repository where I have to create single program which has to be executable on all platforms. Here is my program:

```
def DataSet():
 
 **PATH  = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"**
 DataSet.driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
 DataSet.driver.get(url)   
 r = input('\n'+"Enter the dataset name: ")
 login_form = DataSet.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h1[contains(text(),'{}')]".format(r))
 check = login_form.click() 
 urr = DataSet.driver.current_url
```

Here the **PATH** which I'm defining is not same in all windows, mac and Linux. Is there any solution for this, please reply soon. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could take different approaches to solve this, Here are a few solutions:

> Using Docker to distribute your application (Most Preferred).

Once you containerize your application/program it runs the same regardless of the platform on which it runs. The chromedriver should also be packaged along with the docker container.

Here is a sample reference of `Dockerfile` to use chromedriver and selenium: [Sample Dockerfile for Python-Selenium-Chromedriver](https://gitlab.com/snippets/1921886)

The second approach would be to check for the Operating System and then look out for chromedriver in platform-specific locations. Incase if chromedriver is not present ask the application user to install in a specific location (add PATH as well) and then use the application.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest defining the path to chromedriver.exe as an environment variable and then you call that variable in your code as per following :

```
path  = os.getenv('chromedriver_path')
```

and in the client machine, add the `chromedriver_path` environment variable and set it's value to the proper path

Comment: yes, I can do this but it wont be the same in my client system too. I cant tell them to download the chromedriver. I'm actually creating a **library package** which is used by any of the user.

Answer (score 0):

in windows we are using chromedriver,.exe but in mac we are using chromedriver

if you maintain framework you can do this
You need to keep this drivers into resouces folder and  by using propertyfilereader you can use accouring platform level